# how to install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall

Tags: linux, oracle11g

just completed installing `oracle linux 6 update 2` on my virtual box and i have been trying to install `oracle 11gr2` on the same operating system i am following the installation guide but i have encountered some problems when i run this command on my terminal

```
yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
```

i am getting an error

```
no package oracle-rdbms-server-11gr2-preinstall available
error nothing to do
```

is there any way i am doing this wrongly??how can i install the `oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It seem you don't have oracle repository configured, do following:**

As an authorized user (for example, root), retrieve the file that configures repository locations:

```
$sudo cd /etc/yum.repos.d

$sudo wget http://public-yum.oracle.com/public-yum-ol6.repo
```

Using a text editor, modify the file, changing the field `enabled=0` to `enabled=1` to reflect repositories that correspond to the machine's operating system release.

Next, install the `oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall` RPM using the yum install command.

The output in Listing 1 shows how the installation checks dependencies and then downloads and installs the required packages.

```
$sudo yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mv /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle-ol6.repo /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle.repo
```

Answer (score 0):

I've given :

```
yum install oracle-rdbms-server-11gR2-preinstall.x86_64
```

and works perfectly